# Problems to compile source code with wxWidgets (MinGW mode) on Windows 10

Tags: c++, c, windows, compilation, wxwidgets

I am having serious problems to compile a code in Windows (regard3d at http://www.regard3d.org). I have read so many post (two days blocked on this problem) here at stackoverflow and other sites, but without success.

The problem is that it needs wxWidgets. For that I am using MinGW. I have VS Community (the latest version). I run my CMakeLists.txt and everytime I get the message

```
Could NOT find wxWidgets (missing: wxwidgets_LIBRARIES wxwidgets_INCLUDE_DIRS)
```

I included the wxWidgets installation directory (which is `C:\wxWidgets-3.1.0`) in `PATH` variable (I restarted to it takes effect) and created the variable `WXWIN` (that also contains the installation directory).

The question: What can I do to solve it?

I think the problem is not building the wxWidgets, but make it be found my cmake.  As mentioned, I built it using MinGW, thus I have the folder `C:\wxWidgets-3.1.0\lib\gcc_dll` and the folder `C:\wxWidgets-3.1.0\include` which contains two more folders named `wx` and `msvc`. I am using the following settings before call the cmake:

```
set wxWidgets_ROOT_DIR=C:\wxWidgets-3.1.0
set R3D_ALT_wxWidgets_INCLUDE_DIRS=include
set R3D_ALT_wxWidgets_LIBRARIES=lib\gcc_dll 
set wxWidgets_CONFIG_EXECUTABLE=build\msw
```

Comment: I think you have to modify FindwxWidgets.cmake in cmake-3.x/share/cmake-3.x/modules. at line 468 you can insert wxWidgets-3.1.0. On my computer I have defined too wxDir=c:\wxWidgets-3.1.0 and wxWin=c:\wxWidgets-3.1.0

Comment: @DiegoCoelho, did you compile the wxWidgets? If yes - did you use MinGW or VS? Keep in mind you can directly use VS to compile it and then link to you own project - no CMake is required.  OK, Looking at the question I believe you should declare wxwidgets_LIBRARIES and wxwidgets_INCLUDE_DIRS instead of the "R3D_ALT..." ones, just like the error says.

Comment: **1.-** Do you have the lastest version of cmake?

Comment: Joel, yes, I just downloaded/installed yesterday. Igor, Many thanks, I settled that yesterday and compiled with VS too (not only MinGW) and it worked!!! Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not very familiar with wxWidgets (so this should probably be a comment, but I can't comment because reasons......), but a quick hack that should work is just throwing the path to the library in LD_LIBRARY_PATH or including it by adding

```
CPPFLAGS += -L C:\wxWidgets-3.1.0\lib\gcc_dll -I C:\wxWidgets-3.1.0\include
```

to your makefile.

Failing that, you could explicitly set the environmental variables it's complaining about outside of the makefile.

Again, sorry, this should be a comment. It's not... If someone wants to copy it to a comment and delete this, that'd be grand.

Answer (score 0):

Thank all of you. Solved! Yesterday I compiled both with MinGW and VS and settled the wxWidgets-3.1.0_INCLUDE_DIRS and it worked!